# creating my own function that would work with and without jQuery selectors

Tags: jquery

consider this function:

```
jQuery.fn.MyFunction = function (event) {
   alert(this.text());
}
```

I want to call it in two ways:

```
$('#myElement').bind('click', MyFunction );
```

and

```
$("#myOtherElement").click(function (event) {
   //some processing
   this.MyFunction(event);
}
```

What is the correct way to declare myFuntion to allow for both of these scenarios?

here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4Z4fQ/5/ but I seem to have jsfiddle issues with binding to my start button also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Z4fQ/8/) of it working.

The main issue you were having is that you never added your closing parenthesis when you bind the click event to `myOtherElement`

Html

```
<div id='myElement'>
    My Element
</div>
<div id='myOtherElement'>
    My Other Element
</div>
```

js

```
jQuery.fn.MyFunction = function (event) {
   alert('My function was called');
   alert($(this).text());
};

$('#myElement').bind('click', $.fn.MyFunction);
$("#myOtherElement").click(function (event) {
   //some processing

   $(this).MyFunction(event);
});
```